# AWS DynamoDB putItem if value is exists in another item`s pk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to add new item to table with a condition.

```
PK          |SK         |Name       |categoryId |Desc
----------------------------------------------------
product_1   |profile    |xxx        |team_1     |
product_2   |profile    |xxx        |           |
category_1  |meta       |           |           |xxx
```

I have a table like above. And I want to add new product with a condition, (category_1 if exists).

I have checked the documentation of AWS, but I couldn't find any solution. Is there any way for this which you know ? :)

Comment: You want to add category 1 if it exists? That doesn't make sense - could you please rephrase? *What* do you want to add exactly and *when*?

Comment: There are several category like category_1 , _2 etc. And when I add new item for product, I want to check that category is exists or not

Comment: And then do what? So e.g. only add `sampleProduct` with a category ID of `5` if 5 exists in the `categoryId` column? Can you please add an example to your question?

Comment: You also have `category_1` in PK which is confusing considering you also have a `categoryId` "column"